# How many numbers does a three sided pyramid contain?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, finite-differences

> Find a closed formula of the amount of balls of a three side pyramids that is constituted of only balls.

A three sided pyramid contains $1$ ball on the first layer, $3$ on the second one, $6$ on the $3^{rd}$ layer, 10 on the $4^{th}$ layer, 15 on the $5^{th}$ one and 21 on the $6^{th}$.

So for the amount of balls just add the previous numbers up to get the following sequence.

$$1,4,10,20,35,54,\ldots $$

If you perform the finite difference method of Newton you'll get. 
$$3,6,10,15,21,\ldots $$
$$3,4,5,6,\ldots $$ 
$$1,1,1,$$

So the closed formula needs to have a polynomial of $4^{th}$ degree.
$P(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e $

I've already solved the matrix of these unknowns. But if you want to do it on your own feel free to verify my solution.

I got that $P(x) = \frac 16 x^3 + \frac 12 x^2 + \frac 13 x$

Now I need to prove this with induction.

$\underline {n=1}$: $\frac 16 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 = 1 $

$\underline {n=k}$: Suppose this formula holds for $P(k) = \frac 16 k^3 + \frac 12 k^2 + \frac 13 k$ with $k\gt 0$

$\underline {n=k+1}$:

$P(k+1) = P(k) + \ldots$

From here on I'm left blank on what to do next because I don't know what to add with $P(k)$ to get $P(k+1)$.

Comment: These numbers are often called *tetrahedral numbers*.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info but can you answer my question please.

Comment: The term you add to $P(k)$ to get $P(k+1)$ is the size of the $k+1$st layer.  This size is a *triangular number*, probably a familiar expression when you work it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reference @hardmath I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my question because it took me a while to elaborate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you solved the recurrence relation, you didn't actually find what it was. However, just note that
$$P(k+1)=P(k)+(P(k+1)-P(k))$$

Comment: I meant "closed formula".I'll edit it. And your approach isn't something my professort would like to see.

Comment: I've showed him some ways to give inductions from the general way of proving this namely P(k+1) = P(k) + k+1 . He wants his students to maintain this form

Comment: @Anonymous That's a pretty massive typo. By the way, I meant to substitute the explicit values. You said you didn't know what to add, but $P(k+1)-P(k)$ is exactly what you add, whether it looks that way or not.

Comment: Yeah I shouldn't have done that. I tried that already but that is not elegant at all.

Comment: Maybe I need to find the recurrence relation first.

Comment: In short form $P(k+1) - P(k) = \frac 12 k^2 + \frac 32 k + 1$

Comment: @Anonymous If your formula is correct, my answer gives you the recurrence relation explicitly. Just write $P(k+1)-P(k)$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: But I'm certain my professor or teacher won't approve this way. He wants something that follows out of the closed formula immediately or maybe some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: My apologies for my unrespectful answers but I'm just getting frustrated by my professor because he wants it his way. And I don't always get it his way. So I just stick with my original proofs.